# Quantising the Electromagnetic Field in QED

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, electromagnetism, photons, quantum-electrodynamics

[image]

How exactly do you derive this result?

Comment: Have you not googled / checked the main literature? It is 100% in all good QED books

Comment: My Answer: They are simple harmonic oscillators (SHO) you learn in Quantum Mechanics. But just change $a$ and $a^\dagger$ to k dependence Fourier modes $a_k$ and $a_k^\dagger$, with a proper **normalization** (Lorentz invariant volume form) and spin-1 massless **polarization**. They are the solutions of free Maxwell equations from the Maxwell Lagrangian |F|^2.

Comment: Take any relativistic (bosonic) field (for instance the electromagnetic field), and take the spatial Fourier transform, and you will get a set of harmonic oscillators. So quantizing the field is the same thing that quantizing harmonic oscillators, and you know how to do that...

Comment: Can you demonstrate this please.

Answer (score 2):

It is similar to how you derive a simple harmonic oscillators modes by diagonalizng a quadratic Hamiltonian in Quantum Mechanics (everyone remembers it, right?):
$$
H \propto \hat{X}^2+\hat{P}^2 \propto \hbar \omega (a^\dagger a+1/2)
$$

Here for photon fields, they are similar simple harmonic oscillators (SHO) you had learned in Quantum Mechanics.

But just:

(1) change $a$ and $a^\dagger$ to $k$ dependence Fourier modes $a_k$ and $a_k^\dagger$.

With a proper normalization (Lorentz invariant volume form: check Chap. 1 of [Peskin and Schroeder "Intro to QFT"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201503972)) and spin-1 massless polarization (check Chap. 4,5 of [Peskin and Schroeder "Intro to QFT"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201503972)).

(2) Check they are the solutions of free Maxwell equations from the Maxwell Lagrangian $$L  =\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} \propto \vec{E}^2-\vec{B}^2$$. Here $F=dA$. You can derive the EOMs.

A good exercise (for you?) is to write down the Hamiltonian by the canonical approach change 
$$L \to H = \dot{q} p-L(q, \dot{q})$$.
Find the conjugate momentum of $p$ from the $q$ ($q$ as $A(x,t)$ field). You will see explicitly why this Hamiltonian again has the quadratic form 
$$H \propto \vec{E}^2+\vec{B}^2 \propto \sum_k \hbar \omega_k (a_k^\dagger a_k+1/2)  .$$ 
That is why the quantization is exactly the SHO form you wrote in the question. ps. It is also a good review to compare it to the spin-0 scalar boson case. Check Chap. 1 of [Peskin and Schroeder "Intro to QFT."](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201503972)

If you ask more explicit result, you can also refer to [the calculation here and Ref therein the bottom of that page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field). Hope it helps somehow. :-)